# PHP calls the wrong URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using WP eCommerce snd the lines of PHP code below is supposed to link to this [page](http://allfashionsunglasses.com/products-page/) but it rather links it to the wrong [one](http://allfashionsunglasses.com/products-page-2/) which is

```
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="empty">
        <?php _e('Your shopping cart is empty', 'wpsc'); ?><br />
        <a target="_parent" href="<?php echo get_option('product_list_url'); ?>" class="visitshop" title="<?php _e('Visit Shop', 'wpsc'); ?>"><?php _e('Visit the shop', 'wpsc'); ?></a>    
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
wpsc_google_checkout();


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did found out that there was a duplicate URL and it calls the most recent of the 2. Everything became okay, the moment I delted the duplicate and then deactivate and re-activated the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

All that code is doing is location the option Product_list_url and getting the url in it. The url is probably wrong in that option. That option is either stored in the admin settings for that plugin or in the code. First check in the admin settings for that plugin and locate the option Product List URL or something like that. Other option is to do a code wide search for "product_list_url and see if it's hardcoded anywhere. That's my two cents and how I usually track down stuff in WP or Drupal.